# How do I set a dictionary key to the variable name and not value using RobotFramework

Tags: dictionary, robotframework

I need to create a dictionary and set values to them like so.

```
${dn-name}    Set Variable    Sweety
${dn-date}    Set VAriable    10-02-2017
```

Now I need to set it to a dictionary so it looks like this :

```
${My_Dict} = {${dn-name}:Sweety, ${dn-date}:10-02-2017}
```

I am going to save this into a file later and then extract it later. 
How can I do that using Create Dictionary or Set To Dictionary Keyword in Robot Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use built-in keyword [Create Dictionary](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Create%20Dictionary) to create a dictionary:

```
*** Test cases ***
Example
    ${dn-name}    Set Variable    Sweety
    ${dn-date}    Set Variable    10-02-2017    
    &{My_Dict}    Create dictionary  
    ...    dn-name=${dn-name}  dn-date=${dn-date}
    log           dictionary: &{My_Dict}
```

When I run the above test and examine the log, the final step shows up like this in the log:

```
12:43:20.505    INFO    dictionary: {u'dn-name': u'Sweety', u'dn-date': u'10-02-2017'}
```